# Dynamic where clause in linq query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

Sorry for my bad English. I have a problem. I want to create dynamic `where` clause in a LINQ query. I have one list object name "list1" having values `Country`, `City`, `State` and one datatable that has column named `Name`, `Lastname`, `Country`, `City`, `State`. I want to compare list1 values with datatable columns and get null / empty rows.

So I want a LINQ query like this:

```
var query = from p in datatable.AsEnumerable()
            where list1 == null
            select p
```

but it returns an error. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: So, you have a list of objects, and this object has properties for Country, City, and State.  You want to find all the records from the table in the database which do NOT match at least one value in your object list?

Comment: Yes at least one value to match

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's get going - your query is ridiculously bad.

- You should not have `datatable.AsEnumerable` - that forces a table scan (running through the whole table).
- Second, you have to code all fields expressively. This is going to get nasty - per definition Depending on size of list this will be very bad.

In general, every query is an `IQueryable` itself, so you can chain where conditions.VERY nice - I use that partially myself, defining the core query, then adding additional where clauses as needed (by input parameter) before executing.

Sadly, comparing a table against a list of elements by individual field match is as bad as it gets from the sql level.